# how to install packages from pypi to anaconda?

Tags: python, installation, package, anaconda, pypi

I've been using Anaconda in Window for all my python coding. I've got a few questions:

1. How do I check all the existing packages/modules I've installed? What commands do I need to type?
2. How do I install third-party packages, especially those available in pypi? Sometimes when I download some packages like opencv, I just need to copy the file to the folder 'C:\Users\user\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages', and then type 'import cv2' in the ipython console (I'm using Spyder which is included in Anaconda), which is really easy. But more often, when I see some packages in pypi, I need to download the gz file. Inside the folder, there is a setup.py. When I try to run it, I get errors, like the following:

   ```
   SystemExit: usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2     [cmd2_opts] ...]
      or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
      or: setup.py --help-commands
      or: setup.py cmd --help

   error: no commands supplied
   ```

   What's wrong? Do I need to unzip the gz file into some specified folders first before running setup.py? Do I need to type any commands or codes in the ipython console?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Find the installation directory and look in the packages directory

2) From the Anaconda command line,

```
conda install <pkg name>
```

or if its in a tarball

```
conda install <tar-file-name>.tar
```

[Anaconda FAQ](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/faq.html)

Comment: do I need to unzip the gz file and move it to a specified folder first?

Comment: You can install directly from tar if you use the full path name for the file. At least it has always worked for me so far.